# Combine data of double rows as output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an example table with Ids and Names, I would like to get a new table with unique Ids and the names of one column combined (grouped by ID).
My data looks like this (SQL Server 2017 & 2019 - SSMS):

```
HouseId,    Names
1,  William
1,  James
1,  Mason
1,  Ella
1,  Jackson
1,  Evelyn
2,  Colton
2,  Robert
3,  Austin
3,  Cooper
3,  Parker
4,  Daisy
5,  Edward
5,  River
```

My goal is to get the following output with a qry:

```
HouseId,    Names
1,  William, James, Mason, Ella, Jackson and Evelyn
2,  Colton and Robert
3,  Austin, Cooper and Parker
4,  Daisy
5,  Edward and River
```

Does anybody has a tip/suggestion how to do this easy without making it to complicated by a SQL code? The double values by houseid are between 2 and 60.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Please tag your dbms (sql server, Oracle, mysql...) and version. Some have a native function, some don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desire for `and` makes this quite tricky.  You seem to care about the ordering of the names -- preserving the ordering from the original table.  To handle that, I will assume there is an ordering column:

```
select houseid,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then max(name)
             else concat(string_agg(case when id <> max_id then name end, ', ') within group (order by id),
                         ' and ',
                         max(case when id = max_id then name end)
                        )
        end) as names
from (select t.*, max(id) over (partition by houseid) as max_id
      from t
     ) t
group by houseid;
```

If you don't have such an id to preserver the ordering, you can use `name` instead.  The results have the format you want, but without an ordering column, the ordering cannot be preserved.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0db63016a6880ab1caebe0ecdea61d2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi, I get the following error: STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: Try replacing `string_agg(case when id <> max_id then name end, ', ')` with `string_agg(case when id <> max_id then CAST(name as nvarchar(max)) end, ', ')`

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not specify what DBMS you are using, I will list the most used ones.

MySQL (I believe 5+)

```
SELECT HouseId, GROUP_CONCAT(Names SEPARATOR ', ') AS Names
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HouseId;
```

Oracle (11g +)

```
SELECT HouseId, LISTAGG(Names, ', ') AS Names
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HouseId;
```

Postgres (9+)

```
SELECT HouseId, STRING_AGG(Names, ', ') AS Names
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HouseId;
```

SQL Server (2017+)

```
SELECT HouseId, STRING_AGG(Names, ', ') AS Names
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HouseId;
```

For older versions of Oracle, MySQL, Postgres you can write your own function. For SQL Server you can use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to achieve something similar. For Postgres that supports `array_to_string` you can use it in conjunction with `array_agg`.

Note that this will only separate the values with a comma and a space, if you want the last one to be separated by the word `and` it gets trickier.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on the upvotes.  This doesn't answer the question.  Although quite useful, the question is answers is "how do I do aggregate string concatenation in lots of databases".  The format the OP is asking for explicitly has an `and` for the last element.